# Can I prove elastic impulse like that?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision

This is not a homework question, I have got the correct solution; My question is about: "Why does my kind of solution not work?"

Given the following:

- mass 1: 5kg, velocity 1: 4m/s in positive x direction
- mass 2 :  10kg, velocity 2: 3m/s in negative x direction
- mass 2 stopped after collision

question: is the collision elastic?

answer from the book (to proof that I do not try to solve homework): 
"No because $\Delta E_{kin}=-75Joule$

My trial was different and I just wonder if I could have done it like this:

Since mass 2 stopped after collision, I used a formula for elastic collision:

$v_{2,final}=\frac{2m_{1}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}*v_{1,initial}$

$0=\frac{2*5kg}{5kg+10kg}*4m/s$ => you can clearly see that this equation doesn't work so, I argued that it is not elastic. Am I correct with this method?

Comment: Yes it's quite correct.

Comment: How would you know $\Delta E$?

Comment: @pfnuesel - from conservation of momentum to get the final velocity of mass 1 then calculation of the total kinetic energy at the end for masses 1 and 2 compared to the initial kinetic energies of masses 1 and 2